# Create self-function and get ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, function, valueerror

I create a function like below:

```
import pandas as pd
DATAPATH = "path/"

df_orig = pd.read_csv(DATAPATH + "file.csv" , dtype=str, sep = "|")

def test(df = None, df2 = None):
    if df == None:
        pass
    elif not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        df_in = pd.read_csv(DATAPATH + df + ".csv", dtype=str, sep = "|")
        print(f'============ Number of obs. in {df} ============\n{df_in.shape[0]:,}\n')
        print(f'============ First 10 Records of {df}.csv ============\n{df_in.head(10)}\n\n\n')
        print(f'============ Last 10 Records of {df}.csv ============\n{df_in.tail(10)}\n\n\n')
    else:
        df_in = df
        print(f'============ Number of obs. ============\n{df_in.shape[0]:,}\n')
        print(f'============ First 10 Records ============\n{df_in.head(10)}\n\n\n')
        print(f'============ Last 10 Records ============\n{df_in.tail(10)}\n\n\n')

    if df2 == None:
        pass
    elif not isinstance(df2 , pd.DataFrame):
        df_in2 = pd.read_csv(DATAPATH + df2 + ".csv", dtype=str, sep = "|")
        print(f'============ Number of obs. in {df2} ============\n{df_in2.shape[0]:,}\n')
        print(f'============ First 10 Records of {df2}.csv ============\n{df_in2.head(10)}\n\n\n')
        print(f'============ Last 10 Records of {df2}.csv ============\n{df_in2.tail(10)}\n\n\n')
    else:
        df_in2 = df2
        print(f'============ Number of obs. ============\n{df_in2.shape[0]:,}\n')
        print(f'============ First 10 Records ============\n{ddf_in2_in.head(10)}\n\n\n')
        print(f'============ Last 10 Records ============\n{df_in2.tail(10)}\n\n\n')


test(df = df_orig, df2 = None)
```

However, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    test(df = df_orig)
  File "test.py", line 7, in test
    if df == None:
  File "/mypath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1443, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestion on this?
Do I use the wrong logic for `if df == None:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) way of checking if DataFrames are empty:

```py
if df.empty:
    # do something
```

Another way is to check the length:

```py
if len(df) == 0:
    # do something
```

Edit: the comments lead me to believe that your order of operations is wrong here.

```py
def test(df = None):
    if not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        pass # do whatever
    elif df.empty:
        pass # do whatever else
```

`None` has no length, so `len()` throws an error, while `df.empty` will throw an error if df is `None` as well. Simply check if df is a DatFrame first, this will take care of the `None` values.

Comment: Even I changed `not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)` to `df.empty`, still got the same error. I want to have `if df == None:
        pass` leave there so I can skip this part and do next thing since above is just a simple example.

Comment: Try len(df) == 0?

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
`

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comment, but you weren't supposed to change `not isinstance` to `df.empty`, but `df == none` to `df.empty` or the length one.

Comment: I am fairly certain your issue lies with the order of operations. Check if it is an instance first, editing my answer.

Comment: I change `if df == None:` to `if len(df) == 0:` and `elif not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):` to `elif df.empty:`, but got `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` when I call `test(df = None, df2 = None)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231535/discussion-between-i-m-and-peter-chen).